# Highlight area in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

How can I highlight an area/region on Google Maps v2 Android? I also have a list of geopoints of that particular region. It needs to highlight that region when you scroll to that region. It needs to fill color for nearby region to differentiate from each other so each region should have a different color.

Comment: share requirement example image.

Comment: Hello Swati.Something like this http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=641&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=eCg4Y6w_JozL-M:&imgrefurl=http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/auto-highlight-areas-of-any-map-image/&docid=Y77oipvJRiVX2M&imgurl=http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/map-highlight-mapper.gif&w=473&h=276&ei=nbA5UsHKK8y0iQf1rYHgCg&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=171&tbnw=294&start=0&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0&tx=203&ty=262

Comment: http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=641&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=gKOb9ftgJYPEtM:&imgrefurl=http://mapsof.net/map/columbia-ct-highlight&docid=ireQ5xghxuXFlM&imgurl=http://mapsof.net/uploads/static-maps/columbia_ct_highlight.png&w=574&h=439&ei=nbA5UsHKK8y0iQf1rYHgCg&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=196&tbnw=257&start=0&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0&tx=739&ty=223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to draw a polygon by selecting some points on map. Here is the code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMapClickListener, 
    OnMapLongClickListener, 
    OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap myMap;
    Location myLocation;
    boolean markerClicked;
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
    Polygon polygon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) manager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) 
    {
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point).title(point.toString()));

        markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) 
    {

        if(markerClicked)
        {
            if(polygon != null)
            {
                polygon.remove();
                polygon = null;
            }

            polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
            polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
            polygonOptions.strokeWidth(5);
            polygonOptions.fillColor(0x884d4d4d);

            polygon = myMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
            marker.remove();

        }
        else    
        {
            if(polygon != null)
            {
                polygon.remove();
                polygon = null;
            }

            polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
            markerClicked = true;
            marker.remove();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Long Press to select locations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >


 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

manfiest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.polygononmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapwithsession.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="google.map.ver2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.polygononmap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your api key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

now use long press to select points on map and click on marker will draw polygon accordingly.. I thing this will help.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEM90r9r9vI
- for details https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon

Comment: Hello Swati sorry for the late reply .I will try it today and get back to you for further queries.I have a list of 200 geo points to add in  myMap.addPolygon .I was getting an error the other day .Will implement again and let you know .Thanks.

Comment: ok no problem its more easier if u already have the points. M telling u the way. just add all those point to an arraylist of LatLng like ArrayList points = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); and then draw it. ask me if face problem i will send u the codes

Answer (score 2):

You just draw a [`Polygon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polygons) on your map and fill it with the color you need.

Comment: Thanks for your input sir.but its irregular boundary of a sector and may not be square or rectangle.How do I do that ?

Comment: Just add more points to your polygon. Polygons don't need to be squares or rectangles.

Comment: So all the geopoints alloted to that region will become irregular ?? like the img above ?